# item without additional space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I  have a `recyclerview` in my layout.

My problem is additional space in `recyclerview`.

How can I remove it?

here is my code:

recycler item :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgGalleryImage"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/slider1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

recuclerview :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/photographerImageGalleryRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

and the code:

```
        List<BundlePhotographerImageGallery> photographerImageGalleryList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        BundlePhotographerImageGallery bundlePhotographerImageGallery = new BundlePhotographerImageGallery();
        bundlePhotographerImageGallery.image = "slider1";
        photographerImageGalleryList.add(bundlePhotographerImageGallery);
    }

    AdapterPhotographerImageGalleryRecycler adapterPhotographerImageGalleryRecycler = new AdapterPhotographerImageGalleryRecycler(photographerImageGalleryList, getApplicationContext());
    photographerImageGalleryRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager1);
    photographerImageGalleryRecycler.setAdapter(adapterPhotographerImageGalleryRecycler);
```

and image:
[image]

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" replace this with android:layout_width="wrap_content" in RecycleView and also remove margin from ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove margins from recycler view and imageview